# Bash completion using output from script

Tags: bash, tab-completion

I know there are a lot of tutorials on bash completion, but I just can't figure this out.

All I want is this. If I type myscript[tab][tab], then "myscript list-commands" is run. It will output a space delimited list of available commands (but I can output it however is appropriate). That output list is used for tab completion.

What do I put it my .bashrc to make that happen?

Comment: The  [`complete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) builtin can specify the type of autocompletion  for a given function. For more info see `help complete` or `man bash`

Comment: That's close to what I want. When I asked the original question, I didn't realize that completion works not just for the first option but for all subsequent options. Here's what I have so far which isn't quite what I want:

complete -C "myscript list-commands" myscript

That means that if I type in a command like this:

myscript [tab][tab]

I get a list of commands. Then if I complete one of the commands, then hit [tab][tab] again, I get the list of commands again. What I want is that second time I get a list of *.sql files in the current directory. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using a list of *words/commands* that your script supports:

Put the following into your `.bashrc` to have your script `myscript` support the commands `add`, `list`, `delete`:

```
complete -W "add list delete" myscript
```

This will leads to

```
> myscript [tab][tab]
add list delete
```

Hope this help. For further, more dynamic options than a simple wordlist have a look at the manpage of the `complete` command: https://ss64.com/osx/complete.html